# Why I'm getting a 500 internal error when validate Recaptcha V2, Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, recaptcha, production-environment

I'm using Django and when I want to submit my contact form, i have to validate my google recaptcha. It's working locally but in production I have a 500 internal error and the mail is not sent when the form is correctly fill with the correct captcha.
I added my domain name to the google recaptcha website... I have correct secret key... Again it's working locally

[image: Captcha validate ready to send]

[image: Error after submit]

Answer (score 0):

You may have solved this already, but just for future reference in case it helps someone, I can say that I had a similar issue using the [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha/blob/develop/README.rst) package and I was able to solve it by **removing** the following line from settings.py which I originally needlessly added:

```
RECAPTCHA_PROXY = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', 'https': 'https://127.0.0.1:8000'}
```